# User control for upper case

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I want to create a user control [textbox] which convert all the text in the Upper case. 
In normal web page, I can do it via

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server">
    </asp:TextBox>

    <style type="text/css">
    #TextBox1
       { 
          text-transform: uppercase; 
       } 
</style>
```

I am not aware how to convert them in user control and how can I create my own textbox control which has this feature in build. So that I can drag-drop them from my toolbox and can use it.

Any help?

**Edit**

It would be just like, I want to give one more property to the textbox [Let say: Uppercase="True" or Uppercase="False"] which will decide whether the textbox character will be uppercase or not.

**Edit 1**

[image]

**Edit 2**

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;

namespace UppercaseBox
{
    public class UppercaseTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    {
        public extern Boolean Uppercase 
        { get; 
          set;
        }
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return Uppercase && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text) ? base.Text.ToUpper() : base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = Uppercase && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.ToUpper() : value; ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: create a user control with your code fragment that you provide in your question or do it with `javascript` with `keypress` event

Comment: @Chris: i added a C# version to my answer. Basically, what you've posted looks fine, except for the extern keyword. Unless you're working with a different version of .net (i tested it with 3.5) the code i posted works and so should yours after you remove the extern :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simpler way i see is that you could create a custom control that inherits from TextBox and override the Text property so that it changes the text to uppercase.

```
Public Class UppertextBox
        Inherits Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

        Public Overrides Property Text As String
            Get
                Return MyBase.Text.ToUpper
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                MyBase.Text = value.ToUpper ' no check for null, add it if necessary
            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

The uppercasing could depend on a property of your control, to allow you to customize the textbox in the page using it.

```
Public Class UppertextBox
        Inherits Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox

        Public Property Uppercase As Boolean

        Public Overrides Property Text As String
            Get
                If Uppercase AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(MyBase.Text) Then
                    Return MyBase.Text.ToUpper
                Else
                    Return MyBase.Text
                End If
            End Get
            Set(ByVal value As String)
                If Uppercase AndAlso Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) Then
                    MyBase.Text = value.ToUpper
                Else
                    MyBase.Text = value
                End If

            End Set
        End Property

    End Class
```

Your inherited control could also set its style to uppercase but i'd recommend alternatively using themes if you don't want to bother setting the style at each use

**EDIT**

C# Version would look like

```
public class UppercaseTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
    {
        public Boolean Uppercase { get; set; }
        public override string Text
        {
            get
            {
                return Uppercase && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(base.Text) ? base.Text.ToUpper() : base.Text;
            }
            set
            {
                base.Text = Uppercase && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(value) ? value.ToUpper() : value;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but that will convert it in server side not client side

Comment: @samy Please wait. I am implementing what you have suggested me. I'll get back to you in 5 minutes if I face any issue. I hope you will assist me.

Comment: @Miroprocessor Is it? :-( I want it to be on the client side.

Comment: @Miroprocessor @Chris: The text-transform style will change the display of the text on the client, the control will change it on the server. If you just use the text-tranform, the value is still transmitted with its original casing on the server, even though it displays uppercase on the client. Alternatively, you could use javascript only to change the text on the client, but any disabled javascript on the client would break the uppercasing

Comment: @samy  I am not able to convert it into c#. I am using http://www.carlosag.net/Tools/CodeTranslator/

Comment: @samy till now I have created a class in app_code and it look like this  public class MyTextBox : System.Web.UI.WebControls.TextBox
{
    public MyTextBox()
    {
        //
        // TODO: Add constructor logic here
        //
    }
}

Comment: @samy Later, I will create a separate class library and will place this class in that library to get the DLL. is that right ?

Comment: @samy I have created a new class library. addded a new class UppercaseTextBox. used the same code which you have provided. When I compiled it I got a DLL. Is that I need to add in the toolbox to use it as a control ?

Comment: @Chris That should do the trick. You can use this library as your common repository of custom controls

Comment: I am getting this error while compiling "*must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern*" at **public Boolean Uppercase { get; set; }**

Comment: @samy I put extern in the uppercase and it is now compiled.

Comment: @samy when I tried to add that into my toolbox I am getting error that "**cannot load assembly because get uppercase has no implementation**".. any suggestion ?

Comment: @samy I am updating the question again, please check. Edit 2

Comment: @samy you have done a lot for me. I don't want to trouble you more. I am accepting your answer. If you can assit me in resolving the last error. I will be very greatful to u

Answer (score 2):

first you can use `web user control` contains just one `TextBox` and `Boolean` property called `UpperCase`

**code behind**

```
public Boolean UpperCase
{
    get;
    set;
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<%if(UpperCase) {%>
<style type="text/css">
#TextBox1
   { 
      text-transform: uppercase; 
   } 
</style>
<%} %>
```

in your page add this control

```
<uc1:TextControl ID="TextControl1" runat="server" UpperCase="false"/>
```

**Notice**

I used `ClientIDMode="static"` to keep the `ID` of `TextBox` as it is, that will work if you use `ASP.Net 4.0` if you don't, you will have to use `ClientID` property of `TextBox` to apply the style something like that

```
  <%if(UpperCase) {%>
<style type="text/css">
#<%=TextBox1.ClientID%>
   { 
      text-transform: uppercase; 
   } 
</style>
<%} %>
```

Comment: this is right answer.. user this code will create custom control.. good.

Comment: It works, but you lose the events from the text box and may have to wrap them in the custom control to bubble them up

Comment: +1 can I create a control from it ? because I want it to be in the toolbox ! :-( I am sorry I trouble you.

Comment: @samy which events you talk about?

Comment: @Chris you can drag the `web user control` from `solution explorer` and drop it into design section of your page

Comment: @Miroprocessor: events fired by the webcontrols such as TextChanged, Databinding/bound, etc...

Comment: @samy I think you can fire such events inside the control itself

Answer (score 0):

use style sheet..

input[type=text]
{

text-transform: uppercase; 
}

its easy way effect in all text box

Comment: I want separate control for that, I can't let all my textbox to be in upper case.